# How do I fit a line to this data?

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy

I've got the following data:

[image]

I'm interested in fitting a line on the 'middle bit' (intercept 0). How do I do that? It would be useful to get a figure for the gradient as well.

(FYI These are a list of cash transactions, in and out. The gradient would be the profit or loss).

Here's some of the data:
https://gist.github.com/chrism2671/1081c13b6760878b457a112d2041622f

Comment: Do you mean by 'middle bit' the curve that visually seems to split the data into an upper and a lower part? (Fitting that exactly will be rather difficult.) Do you mean by 'intercept 0' that the line should run through the point [0,0]? The gradient of a line is trivially the slope; unless you want the gradient of the data which would look horrible with these sharp edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.polyfit` and `numpy.poly1d` to achieve that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create data

ls = np.linspace(0, 100)
s = np.random.rand(len(ls))*100 + ls

# Fit the data

z = np.polyfit(ls, s, deg=1)
p = np.poly1d(z)

# Plotting

plt.figure(figsize=(16,4.5))

plt.plot(ls, s, 
         alpha=.75, label='signal')

plt.plot(ls, p(ls), 
         linewidth=1, linestyle='--', color='r', label='polyfit')

plt.legend(ncol=2)
```

[image]

---

Using the data you provided:

[image]